# Get min and max value from object list in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and need to retrieve min and max values from the data set. I tried many ways. But I couldn't find a good way to do this. seek your guideline for this.

I have a class like this.

```
class Speed():
 id = None
 method = None
 speedFrom = None
 speedTo = None
 valid = None
```

Also, I have a list of speed objects with the below sample data.

```
speed_list {
       id=1, method=A, speedFrom=10, SpeedTo=20, valid=false
       id=2, method=B, speedFrom=20, SpeedTo=30, valid=true
       id=1, method=A, speedFrom=30, SpeedTo=40, valid=true
       id=1, method=A, speedFrom=40, SpeedTo=50, valid=true
       id=1, method=A, speedFrom=50, SpeedTo=60, valid=false
      }
```

I need to get the minimum value of **speedFrom** field and maximum value of **speedTo** field from only **valid =true** objects. As of this example, final results should be

> min = 20 and max = 50

Comment: That `speed_list` sample is invalid syntax, so one has to make assumptions about what it *really* contains. It would help if you'd make this a valid Python sample.

Comment: `min((i for i in speed_list if i.valid), key=lambda i: i.speedFrom)`…?

Comment: Are you aware that you defined class attributes? I think you want instance attributes instead. If you don't know the difference then reread the tutorial.

Comment: @deceze yes. actually, it is not the correct syntax. it is just a sample data set. Anyway, your code suggestion saves my day. That is what I need to do. Thank you for your help and quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the speedTo and speedFrom to instance attributes like this:

```
 class Speed: 
      def __init__(self, speedTo, speedFrom):
           self.speedTo = speedTo
           etc.
```

You could get the min and max like this:

minSpeedTo = min([object.speedTo for object in objectsList])
and max the same way.